# Communicating with a classic TCP socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, zeromq, netmq

I'm writing my first application with NetMQ (ZeroMQ implementation for .NET).

I also need to listen to information sent from a client using a traditional TCP socket (a.k.a a non-0MQ socket).

I've seen references to the availability of this socket type in the official ZeroMQ documentation [here](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-socket), (look for ZMQ_STREAM), but there's very few details on how to use it (and that doesn't help much either, the .NET API is quite a bit different from the C++ API).

The [offical NetMQ documentation](http://netmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) also makes no mention of the Streaming socket type.

Finally I had a look over to the Test suite for NetMQ on Github, and found a partial answer to my question in the [method RawSocket](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq/blob/master/src/NetMQ.Tests/SocketTests.cs#L252).

The following snippet works:

```
using (NetMQContext context = NetMQContext.Create())
{
    using (var routerSocket = context.CreateRouterSocket())
    {
        routerSocket.Options.RouterRawSocket = true;
        routerSocket.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5599");

        byte[] id = routerSocket.Receive();
        byte[] message = routerSocket.Receive();

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(id));
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message));
    }
}
```

When using standard TCP/IP test-tools, the byte[] message is printed out nicely, e.g. like this:

```
Hello World!
```

but the byte[] id is printed out like this:

```
 ???♥
```

In other words, I have no clue what's up with the id part. Why is routerSocket.Receive called twice? What is contained within the id? Is this something ZeroMQ/NetMQ specific, or is something TCP/IP specific information being extracted here?

Comment: Refer to the documentation [link](http://netmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/router-dealer/) on RouterSocket. This socket type has an ID in front of every message. It's a binary identifier, so you won't be able to print it out using ASCII.GetString(). You could create an int from the 4 bytes, and print the value of that int if you wanted to see the message ID.

Comment: @Ah, thanks! I was looking at the Steam Sockets for some reason. Thank you, this explains a lot. Does the ID have any meaning when using the RouterSocket to connect a non-0MQ client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Mangist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480165/mangist) for pointing this out.

The answer is in the RouterSocket documentation:

> An identity, sometimes called an address, is just a binary string
>   with no meaning except "this is a unique handle to the connection".
>   Then, when you send a message via a ROUTER socket, you first send an
>   identity frame.
>
> When receiving messages a ZMQ_ROUTER socket shall prepend a message
>   part containing the identity of the originating peer to the message
>   before passing it to the application. Messages received are
>   fair-queued from among all connected peers. When sending messages a
>   ZMQ_ROUTER socket shall remove the first part of the message and use
>   it to determine the identity of the peer the message shall be routed
>   to.
>
> Identities are a difficult concept to understand, but it's essential
>   if you want to become a ZeroMQ expert. The ROUTER socket invents a
>   random identity for each connection with which it works. If there are
>   three REQ sockets connected to a ROUTER socket, it will invent three
>   random identities, one for each REQ socket.

This image illustrates the core concept of the ID frames:

[image]